# wait for return function value before callback triggered

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, callback

I am trying to create a module that fetches all the info one by one and stores it in an array at the end it returns the array, instead of the loop I am using recursion. The problem here is that my main function is not waiting for the return value due to which no value is passed in the callback. I can re-write this async await or promise but if the same type of problem is present in the entire project I don't want to re-write the entire thing. This can be handled by callbacks? or some other way I can resolve it.

```
    const GetRequest = require("./getRequest.js");
module.exports = function GetProcessList(environment, token, processCompleteList, callback) {
    var allProcessDraft = [];
    var loopMaxRun = processCompleteList.data.length -1;
    var a = RecursiveGet(environment, token, processCompleteList, allProcessDraft, loopMaxRun);
    callback(a); //Not waiting for the value
}

//recursion function to get all the data one by one
function RecursiveGet(environment, token, processCompleteList, allProcessDraft, index) {
    var URL = "https://" + environment + "...../rest/process/versionPage?calledFrom=master&pageNo=0&processMasterId=" + processCompleteList.data[index].id + "&recordsPerPage=10&sortType=DESC";
    if (index != 0) {
        GetRequest(URL, token, function (processDraft) {
            allProcessDraft.push(processDraft);
            return RecursiveGet(environment, token, processCompleteList,allProcessDraft, index -1);
        });
    } else { 
        return allProcessDraft;
    }
 }
```

Comment: *"I can re-write this async await or promise"* - If you want to await an asynchronous operation, or queue up a set of asynchronous operations and await all of them, then that seems like a reasonable approach.  What prevents you from doing that?

Comment: 1. I have to rephrase all the functions.
2. Same problem in the entire project.
3. I want to learn the other possible way how I was done without async-await or promise.
4. And the person who used to work on this has not much knowledge about async await or promise so it is easy for him.

Comment: Well, yes.  If you want to re-structure the code then doing that generally involves re-structuring the code.  Currently `GetProcessList` is "not waiting for the value" because presumably `GetRequest` invokes an asynchronous operation.  That operation is not awaited.  Aside from that, the `return` in the callback being passed to `GetRequest` most likely isn't doing what you think.  `RecursiveGet` only returns in the `else` block, the `if` block doesn't actually return anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.

```js
async function RecursiveGet(environment, token, processCompleteList, allProcessDraft, index) {
    var URL = "https://" + environment + "...../rest/process/versionPage?calledFrom=master&pageNo=0&processMasterId=" + processCompleteList.data[index].id + "&recordsPerPage=10&sortType=DESC";
    if (index != 0) {
       const processedDraft = await GetRequest(URL, token);
       allProcessDraft.push(processDraft);
       return RecursiveGet(environment, token, processCompleteList,allProcessDraft, index -1);
    } else { 
        return allProcessDraft;
    }
 }
```

note: make sure GetRequest is async

Comment: thanks for the answer but the problem is GetRequest is not async, I have re-structure all of it over and over again.